# How to open multiple accordions with one click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I facing one problem, I created four accordions left side two (LHS1,LHS2) and right side two (RHS1,RHS2) accordions. Now I'm expand LHS1 then RHS1 also open automatically. Now I'm opened LHS2 then RHS2 open automatically in LHS2 opening time top of LHS1 is collapsed but RHS1 is not collapsed.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel-group" id="LHS">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a id="L1" class="collapsed collapse collapse-link-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href="#collapseOne_L">
                            LHS1
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div><!--/.panel-heading -->
                <div id="collapseOne_L" class="panel-collapse collapseOne collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    Welcome LHS1
                    </div><!--/.panel-body -->
                </div><!--/.panel-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a id="L2" class="collapsed collapse collapse-link-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href="#collapseTwo_L">
                            LHS2
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div><!--/.panel-heading -->
                <div id="collapseTwo_L" class="panel-collapse collapseTwo collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    Welcome LHS2
                    </div><!--/.panel-body -->
                </div><!--/.panel-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.panel --> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel-group" id="RHS">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a id="L1" class="collapsed collapse collapse-link-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href="#collapseOne_R">
                            RHS1
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div><!--/.panel-heading -->
                <div id="collapseOne_R" class="panel-collapse collapseOne collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    Welcome RHS1
                    </div><!--/.panel-body -->
                </div><!--/.panel-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a id="L2" class="collapsed collapse collapse-link-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href="#collapseTwo_R">
                            RHS2
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div><!--/.panel-heading -->
                <div id="collapseTwo_R" class="panel-collapse collapseTwo collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    Welcome RHS2
                    </div><!--/.panel-body -->
                </div><!--/.panel-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.panel --> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).on('click', '.collapse-link-1', function (e) {
//alert("open accordions-->");
$('.collapseOne').collapse('toggle');
});

$(document).on('click', '.collapse-link-2', function (e) {
//alert("open accordions-->");
$('.collapseTwo').collapse('toggle');
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code that actually performs the collapse? Or create a JSFiddle(https://jsfiddle.net) with what you have working at the moment.

Comment: Yes,starting all accordions are collapsed.Now once i click LHS1 then automatically expand/collapse two accordions (LHS1 and RHS1) otherwise click RHS1 it open LHS1 and RSH1 at a time.And click LHS2 automatically expand/collapse two accordions (LHS2 and RHS2) otherwise click RHS2 it open LHS2 and RSH2 at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>**[Fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/kfzv9L4d/1/)**</strike>

You have written `click event` but you are not targeting proper element and this you need to do by giving reference to the clicked `element` or by searching the clicked element's `panel-body`

---

**UPDATE**

> Check inline comments in `JS` for details

---

**[Fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/kfzv9L4d/3/)**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.collapse-link-1', function (e) {
    if($("#collapseTwo_L").hasClass('in')) //if second accordion is open
    {
         $('#collapseTwo_R,#collapseTwo_L').collapse('toggle');
         //toggle second accordion of both right and left
    }
 $('.collapseOne').collapse('toggle');
});

$(document).on('click', '.collapse-link-2', function (e) {
    if($("#collapseOne_L").hasClass('in'))//if first accordion is open
    {
         $('#collapseOne_R,#collapseOne_L').collapse('toggle');
         //toggle first accordion of both right and left
    }
 $('.collapseTwo').collapse('toggle');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-group" id="LHS">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="L1" class="collapsed  collapse-link-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href="#collapseOne_L">
                        LHS1
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div><!--/.panel-heading -->
            <div id="collapseOne_L" class="panel-collapse collapseOne collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                Welcome LHS1
                </div><!--/.panel-body -->
            </div><!--/.panel-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="L2" class="collapsed  collapse-link-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href="#collapseTwo_L">
                        LHS2
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div><!--/.panel-heading -->
            <div id="collapseTwo_L" class="panel-collapse collapseTwo collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                Welcome LHS2
                </div><!--/.panel-body -->
            </div><!--/.panel-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.panel --> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-group" id="RHS">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="L1" class="collapsed  collapse-link-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href="#collapseOne_R">
                        RHS1
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div><!--/.panel-heading -->
            <div id="collapseOne_R" class="panel-collapse collapseOne collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                Welcome RHS1
                </div><!--/.panel-body -->
            </div><!--/.panel-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="L2" class="collapsed collapse-link-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href="#collapseTwo_R">
                        RHS2
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div><!--/.panel-heading -->
            <div id="collapseTwo_R" class="panel-collapse collapseTwo collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                Welcome RHS2
                </div><!--/.panel-body -->
            </div><!--/.panel-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.panel --> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i done this code.but i want once click LHS1 automatically expand/collapse two accordions (LHS1 and RHS1) otherwise click RHS1 it open LHS1 and RSH1 at a time.And click LHS2 automatically expand/collapse two accordions (LHS2 and RHS2) otherwise click RHS2 it open LHS2 and RSH2 at a time

Comment: @NavyaPrasad see **[this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/kfzv9L4d/2/)**.. it works fine.. Whats the problem then?

Comment: @Rao i clicked  LHS1 automatically expanded two accordions (LHS1 and RHS1) is it ok.but not collapsed LHS1 and RHS1 after click LHS2 or RHS2

Comment: So at a time you want to keep open one `accordion` of each side? Am I right?

Comment: Yes.. It is possible?

Comment: In my testing it is failed.Please wait i'm checking.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: @Rao just now i added one more accordion for both sides.Now totally three accordions so how to change script code.

Comment: Hoooo sorry sorry i don't know that is answer accept mark  sorry @Rao present i'm using your answer.

Comment: it is ok now i added LHS3 and RHS3.So how to change script code

Comment: Oops sorry.. Check this **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/kfzv9L4d/5/)** @NavyaPrasad

Comment: panel-collapse is creating problem in code.actually in my application this three accordions are in one main accordion it means parent accordion expand it displays this three accordion.Both sides same.

Comment: first two accordions are working fine but third one is not working.

Comment: I pasted my html code in new answer please check it once.

Comment: You need to edit the question and add the code there instead of posting it as answer...

Comment: @Rao i'm facing one more issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Javascript code here.

[**Workign Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AdityaParab/4y9jzkvh/)

All this can be handled from bootstrap's attribute configuration.

Notice you have an `href` attribute on your `<a>` tags.
<del>The documentations states that</del> The source code for this `collapse` plugin states that the href should contain a `selector` for the target element.

Please note that in

`<a id="L1" class="..." data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href=".collapseOne">`

I have changed the `href` attribute from `#collapseOne_L` to `.collapseOne`

Same thing has been done for the `href`s `collapseOne_R`, `collapseTwo_L` and `collapseTwo_R`

This code would work just fine without explicitly hiding/showing the with javascript.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-group" id="LHS">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="L1" class="collapsed  collapse-link-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href=".collapseOne">
                        LHS1
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div><!--/.panel-heading -->
            <div id="collapseOne_L" class="panel-collapse collapseOne collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                Welcome LHS1
                </div><!--/.panel-body -->
            </div><!--/.panel-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="L2" class="collapsed  collapse-link-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href=".collapseTwo">
                        LHS2
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div><!--/.panel-heading -->
            <div id="collapseTwo_L" class="panel-collapse collapseTwo collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                Welcome LHS2
                </div><!--/.panel-body -->
            </div><!--/.panel-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.panel --> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-group" id="RHS">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="L1" class="collapsed  collapse-link-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href=".collapseOne">
                        RHS1
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div><!--/.panel-heading -->
            <div id="collapseOne_R" class="panel-collapse collapseOne collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                Welcome RHS1
                </div><!--/.panel-body -->
            </div><!--/.panel-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="L2" class="collapsed collapse-link-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href=".collapseTwo">
                        RHS2
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div><!--/.panel-heading -->
            <div id="collapseTwo_R" class="panel-collapse collapseTwo collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                Welcome RHS2
                </div><!--/.panel-body -->
            </div><!--/.panel-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.panel --> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i clicked LHS1 automatically expanded two accordions (LHS1 and RHS1) is it ok.but not collapsed LHS1 and RHS1 after click LHS2 or RHS2

Comment: If you're testing this on fiddle, it won't work becuase I have not included latest bootstrap files. It will work perfectly in your own setup. :)